# NullPointerException at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.isStereotypeWithNameValue

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying for so long but not able to understand why I am getting below error. I have tried all the possible solutions available on the internet.It is a standalone utility to insert the data in the database.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata"})
public class CRDExporterApplication {

    /**
     * Logger: log
     */
    final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CRDExporterApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.text.ParseException {
        ApplicationContext context =new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CRDExporterApplication.class);
        log.info("main: Starting export execution");
        CRDExporterController crdExporterController = context.getBean(CRDExporterController.class);
        try {
            //CRDExporterController crdExporterController = new CRDExporterController();
            crdExporterController.referenceDataCRDGet();
            log.info("main: Export Successful");
        } catch (IOException | ParseException | SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

Please find the controller class to call from the Application class.

```
@Component
public class CRDExporterController {

    @Autowired
    private CRDExporterService crdExporterService;
    /**
     * Logger: log
     */
    final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CRDExporterController.class);

    public void referenceDataCRDGet() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException, SQLException, java.text.ParseException {
            log.info("referenceDataCRDGet: Calling Property file reader");
            EntryExitPropertyFileReader eePropertyFileReader = new EntryExitPropertyFileReader();
            Properties eeProperties = eePropertyFileReader.readFile();
            log.info("referenceDataCRDGet: Reading property file process complete.");
            log.info("referenceDataCRDGet: Calling CRDExportService");
            //crdExporterService.exportCRD(eeProperties);
            crdExporterService.exportExcel(eeProperties);
            log.info("referenceDataCRDGet: CRDExportService process complete.");
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.isStereotypeWithNameValue(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.register(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:87)
    at aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.CRDExporterApplication.main(CRDExporterApplication.java:38)
```

I am using below pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aero.sita.gsl.ee.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>primary-line-data</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>primary-line-data</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <version.maven.surefire.report.plugin>2.22.0</version.maven.surefire.report.plugin>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>www.sita.aero</id>
            <url>scp://</url>
        </site>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>SITA Entry Exit Private Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://10.70.101.235:8080/nexus/repository/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-javaagent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.millij</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-object-mapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
            <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.surefire.report.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.CRDExporterApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.CRDExporterApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add your controller en list of dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for the quick response. I didn't get you.

Comment: Add the definition for `CRDExporterController`, I'm assuming that is the bean that is showing your the error.

Comment: I think you are missing the wireing for `CRDExporterController`  and the calling a method from it.

Comment: I have tried @Autowired on CRDExporterController but that was also giving me the same exception.

Comment: Please add the list of dependencies you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I ahve added the pom.xml file as well.

Comment: You are mixing Spring versions (and imho your dependencies are a mess). The mybatis version you included has Spring 5.1 as a dependency, whereas your test dependency pulls in 4.3. This is trouble waiting to happen. Make sure you are using jars from a single version of a framework else weird things will start to happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Deinum. Yes, it was a issue of spring jars.